# property value assignment & template dom-if , firebase-auth

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication, polymer-1.0

I'm using firebase-auth, having an issue with the loading the page based out value of signedIn. Issue is, signedIn getting initial value as false and then true. Problem is even though user logged in, they can see the signedIn page for sometime and then it will hide. Any ideas to fix this behavior?

```
signedIn - inital load value "false"
signedIn - inital load value "true"
```

```html
<firebase-auth
       app-name="app1"
       id="auth"
       signed-in="{{signedIn}}"
       user="{{user}}"
    on-signed-in-changed="_onSignedInChanged" >        
</firebase-auth>

<template is="dom-if" if="[[!signedIn]]">
        <login></login>
</template>

// executing two times
_signedInValueChanged: function(newVal, oldVal){
        console.log("_signedInValueChanged newVal " + newVal)
        console.log("_signedInValueChanged oldVal " + oldVal)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sweet hack :) 
This issue applies to any page that fetch data to compose their view.

I use page transition everywhere, a simple fade-in and fade-out can give me the extra time needed to adjust the view and still offer a great user experience.
[neon-animation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/neon-animation)

Comment: Thanks Joel. I will check it out, other than the animated delay there is no other alternative right ?

Comment: A default or buffer value would be a security risk.